# how to record index after loop in java script

Tags: javascript, for-loop

im about to make a program that the output obtain the domain of the email. how to do that without built-in function such as  *.map .filter .reduce .split .join .indexOf .findIndex .substring*
i do search  and many answer said i have to use for loop, i can find the "@" and find the "." but how to make those string between "@" and "." to be an output

ex: input = mybest@gmail.com
output = gmail

```
 input = triple2@yahoo.com
 output = yahoo
```

```js
let input = "mybest@gmail.com"
let output = ""
let begin = ""
let end = ""

for (let i = 12; i<input.length; i++){
    if(input[i] == "@"){
        begin += input[i+1]
    }
}

for (let j = 0; j<input.length; j++){
    if(input[j] == "."){
        end += input[j-1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function tmp() {

let input = "mybest@gmail.com"
let output = []
let didReachAt = false

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(input[i] == "@") {
       didReachAt = true
    } else if(input[i] == '.'){
       break
    } else if(didReachAt) {
       output.push(input[i])
    }
}

return output.join('')
}

console.log(tmp())
```

The key here is to only *start* appending to the output when you come across an `@` and *stop* appending when you come across a `.` When you come across a `.`, you know you have your output so you can `break` and return the value.

Comment: Thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = "mybest@gmail.com"

for (let i = 0;i<input.length;i++) {
  if (input[i] === '@') {
    var start = i+1
  } else if (input[i] === '.') {
    var end = i+1
    return 
  }
}

let output = input.substring(start,end)
```

Simple solution although this does not account for errors such as a false input

Comment: Thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

So i can see that you started with javascript, so you can learn better using code like this.

```js
var input = "triple2@yahoo.com"
var domainWithoutCom = input.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]
console.log(domainWithoutCom)
```

`split` can do the job for you!

`EDIT:`

Sorry about that, so i will create one version to you check my answer back :)

Check this, i think that can be improve, but can give you an idea :)

```js
var email = 'calvin.nunes@yahoo.com';
var count = 0;
var domain = '';
var findFirst = false;
var searching = true;
do {
    var char = email[count];
    if (findFirst) {
        if (char == '.') {
            searching = false;
        } else {
            domain += char;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (char == '@') {
            findFirst = true;
        }
    }
    count += 1;
} while (searching == true);

console.log(domain)
```

Comment: @CalvinNunes check this now

Comment: Thx for the answer